# using php tags inside opencart html module

Tags: php, module, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I need to call some php vars inside a html module on opencart, but when i use `<?php ?>` my page renders as `<!--?php ?-->`.

is there a way of doing this using the default HTML module of opencart 2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

`<!--?php ?-->` this comment caused by CKEDITOR. But even without editor PHP will not run in standard OpenCart on client side. Here is a recipe howto deal with custom PHP in HTML module.

Adding extra field in OpenCart HTML module with PHP support.

*admin/view/template/extension/module/html.tpl*, find

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_description; ?></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea name="module_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_description; ?>" id="input-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" class="form-control summernote"><?php echo isset($module_description[$language['language_id']]['description']) ? $module_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add after

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-description2<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>"><?php echo $entry_description; ?> 2</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <textarea name="module_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description2]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_description; ?> 2" id="input-description2<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" class="form-control" style="min-height: 400px;"><?php echo isset($module_description[$language['language_id']]['description2']) ? $module_description[$language['language_id']]['description2'] : ''; ?></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be field for the second description.

*catalog/controller/extension/module/html.php*, find

```
$data['html'] = html_entity_decode($setting['module_description'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')]['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Add after

```
$data['html2'] = html_entity_decode($setting['module_description'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')]['description2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
      
if (preg_match('|<\?php.+?\?>|isu', $data['html2'])) {              
  ob_start();
  @eval('?>' . $data['html2']);
  $data['html2'] = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();           
}
```

This will add a second field and with PHP render.

*catalog/view/theme/default(or YOUR_THEME)/template/extentsion/module/html.tpl*

Add at the end

```
<?php if($html2) { ?>  
  <?php echo $html2; ?>  
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i'm using the default module (module/html) the controller is php and the page where i'm putting him is php also, isn't that enough for him to assume the php tag?

Comment: Those php `<?php ?>`. In which field are you trying to insert it?

Comment: I see. CKeditor makes this comment, just tested. There is a way by adding one more field to your standard HTML module, but without CKeditor. Are you OR with that? I can describe the process if you whant

Comment: i think i'm going to use javascript instead, it's only a var that i need, there's no need for much develop for that, thanks anyway

Comment: but if you want to describe the process for that so it could help another person it's ok by me

Comment: Updated the answer with the process of adding custom field with PHP suppore, see please